# Pull file paths from free form text

Tags: python, regex

I'm developing an application in python to pull multiple types of data from free form text. This text can include: email addresses, URLs, and file paths.

My question is: How can I extract file paths (both Linux and Windows) using a regex while excluding URLs (which tend to look similar to file paths).

I have used a variety of regex expressions to try and pull Linux as well as Windows file paths from the text. However, these expressions also pick up on the URLs. I would like to exclude this from happening.

Currently, I am using the following regular expressions for emails and URLs.

Emails:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

URLs:

```
(http|ftp|https)://([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?
```

The desired end behavior of this application is to store valid email addresses, URLs, and file paths in a data structure.

---

**Here is an example of some text:**

> This is an example of some text which will include email addresses: 
>   example@example.com, websites such as: http://www.example.com, and 
>   file paths like: /Users/example/Documents/example.text and 
>   C:\Windows\System32\ I need to pull out only the file paths
>   both Unix and Windows format.

Comment: Can you also add some sample data that you want to capture as path and confuses with the looks of a URL?

Comment: Sure, I have added an example of some text. All the regular expressions that I have tried identified the a portion of the URL, namely: //www.example.com as a file path.

Comment: Can you also add the regex that you used for matching filepaths? The fix is very simple. Just ensure what you identify as a path should not contain `://` inside it. Give me your regex for path and I will correct it to reject URLs.

Comment: You can use one of the regexes that work for both file path and URLs, and put a condition on file path such as the string matches the regex of file path but not for URL.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi It is not possible to match arbitrary file paths with regex. Especially Linux ones that can contain *any* char. You never know the end of the path and it is easy to over- or undermatch.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, that's correct Wiktor, which is why I asked OP to give his current regex so I can just extend it to reject paths matching containing `://` within it. This was of course assuming OP had a character set in mind while trying to capture the paths as some characters can't appear in a valid path.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's what I was afraid of. After doing lots of search on the topic I've come across a bunch of different potential methods like going though OS syscalls to verify the path. However, the primary issue is simply extracting the file path. Do you see any potential other options besides regular expressions to extract file path information? Or with brute forcing the answer with a complicated string parsing function be the most simple alternative?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi here is one of the regular expressions I tried. Another issue with this one is that it tends to match quite a bit after the file path as well... ```(\\\\?([^\\/]*[\\/])*)([^\\/]+)$```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that properly deals with your example

```
import re

example = "This is an example of some text which will include email addresses: example@example.com, websites such as: http://www.example.com, and file paths like: /Users/example/Documents/example.text and C:\Windows\System32\ I need to pull out only the file paths both Unix and Windows format."

emails = re.findall("(?: )([^ ]*@[^ ]*\.[a-z]{2,3})", example)
urls = re.findall("(?: )((?:http|ftp|https):[^ ,]*)",example)
unix_paths = re.findall("(?: )(/[^ ,]*)(?:[ ,])", example)
windows_paths = re.findall("(?: )(C:\\\\[^ ,]*)(?:[ ,])", example)
```

it uses spaces and commas as delimiters. It doesn't work with paths that are in begging/end of text, but that shouldn't be to hard to correct